# Why nothing will be shown on FirBug while typing characters on Google Search box?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax

Usually websites that have suggestion box, send AJAX requests to server and receive the responses. I tried to intercept the requests that Google search box sends to the server but console of FireBug does not show anything.

I am using autocomplete jQuery plugin, while using that FireBug shows all requests that it sends to back-end. Why is that the case?

Comment: Could be using websockets

Comment: @immibis not sure, websocket is usually used to push responses from server, not sure what are its other advantages over  jQuery that they have chosen it over jQuery.

Comment: check properly it is sending requests

Comment: @ddw147 I am sure it will but not sure how. Could you intercept the requests? if yes, would you provide screen shots?

Comment: i can but if i provide screen shot in answer many will down vote it, because it will not an answer :-(

Comment: It's work correctly... make sure select "All" in firebug and select Log in Firefox Developer Tool

Comment: FireBug is showing what the *page* is doing. The Firefox search field is not part of the page, so FireBug will not see it. Remember, FireBug works for each tab independently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In firebug select "All" to show all logging request

[image]
In firefox developer tool, on Console tab ,select Net drop-down and select XHR

[image]